# Comparison of two topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be any infinite set.

Define,

$T_f$ = $\{\emptyset,X\}\cup$ $\{$$G\subset X$| $X-G$ is finite$\}$ which is the cofinite topology.

And,

$T_c$= $\{\emptyset,X\}\cup$ $\{$$G\subset X$| $X-G$ is countable$\}$ which is the cocountable topology.

I was wondering which one of these is finer than the other ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $G \in T_f$. That means $X \setminus G$ is finite, so in particular $X \setminus G$ is countable. Thus $G \in T_c$.

This prove that $T_f \subset T_c$. This means $T_c$ is finer.

Comment: It isn't too hard to show that $T_c \not\subset T_f$. If $\{a_n\} \subset X$ is an infinite sequence let $G = X \setminus \{a_{2n}\}$. Then $G \in T_c$ but $G \notin T_f$.

Answer (score 0):

every finite set is a countable set but not conversely. this mean that every Tf open set is Tc open but not conversely. therefore Tf is a subset of Tc hence Tc is finer than Tf